# HTML5 and javascript in xcode

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, html, uiwebview

I'm quite new to xcode, because I mostly work with JS and HTML5. I've decided to create a simple webview app that enables me to work with JS and HTML5 (going to put it on Github asap)

Now my question is about accessing certian iPhone features that I cannot use in Safari or Chrome (the reason why I'm creating this).
So the question is: is this possible? for example, I can't access the camera (as a fullscreen background I mean) in an iOS browser, but can I use it in webview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need any method of communicating between UIWebView and the containing app. There *are* libraries out there that do just that, some better some less. In case you do not want them... So to outline the techniques to do that:

- App talking *to* the webView - using `[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScript:...]`
- Webview talking to the app - using url directives. Which is essentialy `window.location = ...` with custom fake urls, and then parsing the NSURLs in the delegate method `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` and of course returning `NO` to prevent actually navigating to your fake urls.

If you find that you are missing consecutive URL requests, you could write a JS function that takes the URLs, puts them all in an array, pops one by one and sending them to the browser in a `setTimeout(..., 0)`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use something like this - [Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/)  or [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/)  ( Both are the same thing )

"Apache Cordova is a set of device APIs that allow a mobile app developer to access native device function such as the camera or accelerometer from JavaScript. Combined with a UI framework such as jQuery Mobile or Dojo Mobile or Sencha Touch, this allows a smartphone app to be developed with just HTML, CSS, and JavaScript."

Here is a description of all the device features cordova or phonegap allow you to use - [Plugin API's](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/cordova_plugins_pluginapis.md.html#Plugin%20APIs)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, is it possible, but using a web app container like [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/).

If you need more info how install it visit [this web](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_ios_index.md.html#iOS%20Platform%20Guide).